# How to dynamically specify type of returnable object in PHP7+?

Tags: php-7

here is a short question:

Is there way in PHP7+ to dynamically specify type of returnable object?

```
class SomeObject
{
   private $object;
   ...

   public function get() :? /* Return Dynamic Object Type */
   {
       return $this->object;
   }
   ...

   public function __construct(/* Receive Dynamic Object Type */)
   {
 
   }
}
```

Of course if I set object type directly it works fine:

```
public function get() :? SomeObjectType
{
   return $this->object;
}
```

But what if it should be set dynamically?